# How to set up SDL_gfx in Xcode 6 with SDL 1.2?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, sdl, sdl-1.2

I'm using SDL 1.2 and I'm not sure how to add SDL_gfx to the Xcode project. I dowloaded the .zip file from [cms.ferzkopp.net](http://cms.ferzkopp.net/index.php/software/13-sdl-gfx). What would need to be done next to get SDL_gfx added in Xcode?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the correct version first of all as you are using SDL 1.2 and not SDL 2.0. Then you need to build the library - there should be detailed instructions in the README file but essentially it a case of doing the following:

Open a terminal window and browse to the extracted source and run the following commands

```
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
make install
```

The default location for the installation is **/usr/local/lib** and **/usr/local/include** so from that you should be able to link the libSDL_gfx.a file in your Xcode project and include the required header files.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this, what exactly do I need to enter in Terminal? I'm getting "No such file or directory."

Comment: After I have entered cd desktop/SDL_gfx-2.0.25 and then ./configure I'm getting configure error: SDL version 1.2.0 not found. Any ideas why?

Comment: Have you got SDL 1.2 installed and how/where did you install it? Also is there any reason you are using SDL 1.2 instead of SDL 2.0?

Comment: I have SDL 1.2 installed and downloaded it from [https://www.libsdl.org/download-1.2.php](https://www.libsdl.org/download-1.2.php). The only reason I'm using SDL 1 is because that's what we are being taught at TAFE and I've noticed that SDL 2 is slightly different.

Comment: Are you able to create and run a normal SDL program i.e not using 3rd party libraries like SDL_gfx

Comment: Yes I am. I'm just not sure why I can't get SDL_gfx to install.

Comment: You have to extract the file you have downloaded. You then open Terminal and browse to that extracted directory which contains all the SDL_gfx source. Then in Terminal put in the commands above one by one. That will build and install SDL_gfx.

Comment: I extracted the folder to the desktop. Then entered cd desktop/SDL_gfx-2.0.25 in Terminal. Then I entered ./autogen.sh and I get the following: cp: /usr/local/share/aclocal/sdl.m4: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `distclean'.  Stop.
./autogen.sh: line 9: aclocal: command not found
./autogen.sh: line 10: libtoolize: command not found
./autogen.sh: line 11: autoreconf: command not found
./autogen.sh: line 15: aclocal: command not found
./autogen.sh: line 16: autoheader: command not found
Now you are ready to run ./configure.

Comment: When I run ./configure I then get "configure: error: *** SDL version 1.2.0 not found!"

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your SDL installation. Suggest removing the SDL install and then using Homebrew/Macports to install it

Comment: Actually I haven't actually installed SDL but I have set it up by copying the framework to Library/Frameworks, setting the search path and adding the templates to the Xcode project (as described on [http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/lesson01/mac/xcode/index.php](http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/lesson01/mac/xcode/index.php)) was this the correct way of setting up SDL to be used with SDL_gfx?